# Clear OS always showing "Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec"

Tags: linux, centos, yum, package-management, clearos

Have been trying to install clear os addon but nothing is working as i am facing this error on every mirror in the .repo file.

```
# yum install squid
http://mirror2-dallas.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror2-dallas.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, **'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds'**)
Trying other mirror.
mirror2-dc.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on mirror2-dc.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '**Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds'**)
Trying other mirror.
mirror1.timburgess.net/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on mirror1.timburgess.net/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '**Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds**')
Trying other mirror.
mirror2-houston.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on mirror2-houston.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
mirror3-toronto.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on mirror3-toronto.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '**Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds**')
Trying other mirror.
mirror2-dallas.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on mirror2-dallas.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, 'O**peration too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds'**)
Trying other mirror.
mirror2-dc.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on mirror2-dc.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
mirror1.timburgess.net/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on mirror1.timburgess.net/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '**Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds**')
Trying other mirror.
mirror3-toronto.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on mirror3-toronto.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '**Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds**')
Trying other mirror.
**Error: failure: repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2 from clearos-core: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.**
```

How can i fix this.i am able to access repo through web,and it seems nothing wrong with the repo.Where can be the problem.

Tried yum clean all but it also didnt help.

Is there a way to fix it as i am not able to install any package in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

how's networking working otherwise? are you able to go to those mirrors manually? did you tried them from another location (to see if the problem maybe not on your end)?

*** UPDATE ***

so here, I took one of URL and downloaded it on my box:

```
$ time wget http://mirror3-toronto.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2
--2012-10-16 13:06:52--  http://mirror3-toronto.clearsdn.com/clearos/core/6/x86_64/repodata/primary.sqlite.bz2
Resolving mirror3-toronto.clearsdn.com... 69.90.141.74
Connecting to mirror3-toronto.clearsdn.com|69.90.141.74|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6952331 (6.6M) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: “primary.sqlite.bz2”

100%[==================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 6,952,331    742K/s   in 6.6s    

2012-10-16 13:06:59 (1.00 MB/s) - “primary.sqlite.bz2” saved [6952331/6952331]


real    0m6.925s
user    0m0.011s
sys 0m0.110s
$
```

seems like speed of mirror is fine, so it must be your box in India is the one that at fault, it could be number of things: your network (errors on interface), route of your ISP, etc. Try to look for mirrors that are closer to your location and not thousands miles away, I don't think there is much can be done if your network is overloaded/slow.

*** UPDATE 2 ***

try to do it on your local box

```
$ ifconfig | grep errors
          RX packets:31133806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22168636 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          RX packets:3329073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3329073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
$
```

if you're not seeing any errors, find out what's your network speed to Internet (ISP)

Comment: Response time is very slow from all the repos.My machine is based in India.

Comment: From other locations its fine...

Comment: other locations? where is other location? Also in India? same provider? same network? or in another country?

Comment: i tried from a VPS located in US.For that response time is fast.

Comment: try from same network

Comment: From same network i got it downloaded.... through browser,but through yum still the same.

Comment: is there a way that i can use my vps to use a forwarding machine to forward traffic to machine.?

Comment: there is a way, but your box in India will probably have same issue connecting to your VPS as mirror, so it's not useful.

Comment: or atleast is there a way to increase the time out from 30s to some higher value.. eventhough connection is slow,it still can get downloaded if i am able to increase the default time out from 30.

Comment: it set on a remote server, but less then 1 byte in 30 sec? i'm not sure if there is a value high enough to do a transfer, like i said you should check your network (local,isp) and/or find a closer mirror.

Comment: 1 byte in 30 seconds? That download would finish in a few hundred years...

Answer (score 11):

There are yum parameters you can tweak to prevent the timeout error.

```
timeout=300 # default is 30
minrate=100 # default is 1000
```

However, if the rate you are achieving is really lower than 1000 and doesn't pick up later in the transfer (for example, a virus scanning proxy) then the transfer time for 1 megabyte would be on the order of a half hour or an hour. But, if you make the timeout long enough, at least it will finish ... eventually. If your transfer speed is less than 1B/s (as seems to be the default minrate with clearos) then your transfer will pretty much never finish anyway, unless hopefully it's a virus scanning proxy trickling data to you.

I'm on Fedora 19 and strangely the minrate setting never took, but by setting the timeout to 5 minutes, I was able to download 12 MB package file. The file transferred in 1:36, but was going under 200 B/s for most of that time and suddenly finished very fast (once the proxy virus scanner finished with it).

The idea is that the proxy will trickle your file at a very low rate to prevent connection timeouts while it does the virus scan, then transfer it at full rate once the file checks out. However, if the trickle rate is lower than yum's minrate, then you end up timing out anyway.

Comment: I find that changing the timeout is sufficient. If you can't get 1000B or 5000B in 5 min then something is really wrong.

Answer (score 8):

From [man yum.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/yum.conf.5.html):

> **minrate** This sets the low speed threshold in bytes per second. If the server is sending data slower than this for at least `timeout' seconds, Yum aborts the connection. The default is`1000'.
>
> **timeout** Number of seconds to wait for a connection before timing out. Defaults to 30 seconds. This may be too short of a time for extremely overloaded sites.

---

You can reduce **minrate** and/or increase **timeoute**. Just add/edit these parameters in **/etc/yum.conf [main]** section. For example:

```
[main]
...
minrate=1
timeout=300
```

Comment: Having said that minrate 1 is really really slow. Maybe it's better an higher value, more safe.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. In my case it turned out I had yum configured to use a local http proxy, and that proxy was not operating correctly.

It was solved by simply editing /etc/yum.conf and removing the line starting with "proxy=". Obviously another way would be to fix the proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar issue on a CentOS 8 virtual machine. Every attempt of running yum update failed with:

> (...): Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://(...).rpm [Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]

The solution, surprisingly, was just to run:

```
yum clean all
```

After that, "yum update" worked as expected.

Source: https://mangolassi.it/topic/20892/centos-7-mirrors-operation-too-slow/4

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue can occur if you are using a http mirror (perhaps a local on-site proxy repository for example) that doesn't support Delta RPMs. The fix in that particular scenario is to add the following line to your /etc/yum.conf file:

```
deltarpm=0
```

Answer (score -5):

make sure that login with root user ..
**su -**
Enter password ---**root password.**.

It is worked for me.